# What is the approach to query a CVS repository from a java program?

Tags: java, cvs

Within a java program, I want to calculate the diff between two versions of a src file in a cvs repository. The cvs repository is on a different machine and the java program on my local machine need to query it. I do not know if there is an exposed API for such a task.

After searching on google, I came to know that there is a `cvs diff` command that performs a similar job but as I said, I donot have the cvs server residing on my local machine to manipulate and configure it as per my needs. Moreover, I need to perform the querying in a java program. In what lines should I proceed with this?

Comment: As an aside, `cvs diff` is used to compare locally checked out code against versions in the repository. If you want to compare two versions directly in the repository you should use `cvs rdiff`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Access CVS repositories from Java with [jCVS](http://www.jcvs.org/).

SVN repository you could access with [SVNKit](http://svnkit.com/).

Comment: FYI - realize this is a very old comment, but the jCVS link is outdated (goes to a shopping website)

Answer (score 0):

You do not need cvs server on local machine, cvs/svn command-line client is enough.